# Binary to integer, need suggestions on this approach.

Tags: c

So I'm working on an assignment where I have to perform different operations but without using the standard arithmetic ones. Part of the assignment is converting the users input as an integer in binary form to the standard readable format.

So if the user inputs 0111, I have to return 7.

My question is, how can I split the input into separate values and then store them in an array? I cannot use the standard operands but I do have functions written for addition, subtraction and multiplication.

So what I'm thinking of doing is setting each value of the integer to an array, then reversing it, and in a while loop converting the values by multiplying the given 0 or 1 by corresponding powers of two and then adding everything up.

Comment: seems like a perfectly reasonable approach, what is your question?

Comment: I just started C recently so the whole pointers situation still messes me up. I keep on getting the address instead of the integer value at the given index. @pankrates

Comment: scanf("%u", &day);
    int array[5];
    array[5]= date;
    printf("%d",array[0]);    ends up giving me the address

Comment: If you have trouble with the actual code of the implementation, post your code and the specific problem you are having with it

Comment: Twp things. 1)You can't assign a value to array[5] since its size is 5 and indexing in c starts from 0. 2) Are you sure you're recieveing an address by printing array[0]? If you haven't assigned a value to array[0], you will get undefined values as the array hasn't been initialized. This value may look like an address to you, but it really isn't.

Comment: Note that `int array[5];` means you can use `array[0]` and `array[4]`, but you cannot legitimately use `array[5]` (though `&array[5]` can be evaluated as an address, but not dereferenced).

Comment: @jonathanLeffler I forgot to mention that I do know the sizes of the arrays since the input represents day/month/year, so the user is asked to provide the appropriate length of 5, 4 and 12.

Comment: Remember that users are hostile; they'll try to subvert your program.  It may not be something you worry about too much just yet — you've got other problems to resolve first — but ultimately, you will ask users to provide data of the appropriate length, but your code will handle whatever data they provide you with, and it will neither crash nor corrupt any important data.  (It may reject it, but it should not crash.)

Comment: @still.Learning ahh so, the way the program was provided has scanf("%u", &day); as the function to get input. I'm assuming due to the & it gives me the address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan it as a string. It has a nice advantage of already being an array:

```
char  input[33];
scanf("%s",input);
```

that gives you an array of characters. They aren't integer which is probably what you want. You can covert it to an array of integers, one character at a time using character arithmetic:

```
array[i] = input[i] - '0';
```

You must stop when input[i] is 0, that is the end of the string. You can reverse the array if you want low order bit first.

Comment: scanf("%u", &day); was originally provided as the way to get input, does the fact that its "%u" change anything?

Comment: %u is an unsigned decimal integer. So if 0111 is input, it will be read as a 111 (one hundred eleven). That's a difficult place to start.

Comment: So I cant take on this approach due to the fact that I get a conflicting types error? I cant seem to set up an array because its unsigned.

Comment: Presumably you mean "stop when `input[i] == '\0'` - `'0'` is not the end of the string, it's (possibly) part of it.

Comment: I said 0, not '0'. 0 == '\0'